# NameError: global name 'shlex' is not defined

Tags: python

I have the following code and running into following error even though shlex is defined..

```
import shlex
import sys
import subprocess
def main ():

    branch_name = sys.argv[1]
    print "branch_name"
    print branch_name
    print "start repo..."
    RepoInitCmd =  'repo init -u git://git.quicinc.com/platform/manifest.git -b ' + branch_name
    proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(RepoInitCmd), stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, error = proc.communicate()
    print "Done repo..."

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "repoinit.py", line 15, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__':
  File "repoinit.py", line 10, in main
    RepoInitCmd =  'repo init -u git://git.quicinc.com/platform/manifest.git -b ' + branch_name
NameError: global name 'shlex' is not defined
```

Comment: Something's weird.  Your error message doesn't match the line of code shown in the traceback.

Comment: Can you delete any `.pyc` files and try again?

Answer (score 3):

If `shlex` name is not defined, it means you haven't imported the module in your code. This means the real code doesn't match what you wrote in the question. If `shlex` was not installed, it would have failed on line `import shlex`.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring to move the `shlex.split` call outside the `subprocess.Popen` might be the fix here.  It was for me when calling `subprocess.run` and getting the same error.

```
import shlex
shlex.split('repo init -u git://git.quicinc.com/platform/manifest.git -b ' + branch_name)
proc = subprocess.Popen(RepoInitCmdArgs, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```